# Why condition is triggered?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

```
$text = 'OMNOMNOM';

if($text == intval($text))
    echo 'yes';
else
    echo 'no';
```

Why condition is triggered, and we see "yes"? Why `'OMNOMNOM' == 0`? What's the catch?

**UPD:**

If I write `if('qwe' == 1)`, conditional return false, and if I write `if('qwe' == 0)`, conditional return true... Why condition checked in integer, not in string?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a string consists only of numbers? you might be better looking at something like if(preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$text)) {

Comment: @Matt.C I already use `ctype_digit()` function, but previously I want use method specified in this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because by using `==` PHP tries to cast the values to the same type (in this case it seems like both as integers), if you use `===` then it will not cast and will care about the types (so to get `true` the `type` and `value` needs to be equal).

So try to use:

```
if($text === intval($text))
    echo 'yes';
else
    echo 'no';
```

Comment: I know it, but if I write `if('qwe' == 1)`, conditional return false, and if I write `if('qwe' == 0)`, conditional return true...

Comment: Why condition checked in integer, not in string?

Comment: It's the default behaviour of PHP I think. If any string is compared with an integer, then PHP converts the string to an integer. Maybe I find a source for you.